# Python - displaying non UTF-8 chars, different behaviour for strings and list of strings

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm working on some non-utf-8 text.

I can dump strings with non-utf8 chars substituted to their byte value to terminal as long as I work from a list. If I iterate over the list, I get a decode error.

Whats going on?

```
lines = ['\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Example:- Line 1\x02.\r\n', 
"\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\x02\x13Markup\x13 Example:- Line 2\x8d\n", 
'\xa0\xaExample:- Line 3\r\n', 
'\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\x13Markup\x13 Example:- Line 4\x8d\n']
```

this an example list of lines

```
print lines
```

results in:-

```
['\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0Example:- Line 1\x02.\r\n', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\x02\x13Markup\x13 Example:- Line 2\x8d\n', '\xa0\xaexample:- Line 3\r\n', '\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\x13Markup\x13 Example:- Line 4\x8d\n']
```

[Finished in 0.1s]

however, looping through the lists:-

```
for line in lines:
    print line
```

results in:-

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

How can I maintain a consistent decoding when working on non-utf-8 chars

Comment: Why are you handling non-`unicode`s?

Comment: Try `print repr(line)` - that's what you're seeing for each item when you do `print lines`.

Comment: Because I have documents written in non-utf-8. Printable chars are the same, but markup and control bytes are different.

Comment: @g.d.d.c That works. Thanks. If you add as an answer I'll tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move my comment to an answer and provide more detail:

When you ask the interpreter to print a list, what you actually end up seeing is the result of of the `repr` command for each item in the list.  Often times that means you'll see things like this:

```
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x020C64E0>]
```

With a list of strings, the `repr` value will display escaped sequences.  When you attempt to print a string directly to the console suddenly encoding and character sets become a concern.  You can get access to the escaped output via `print repr(line)`.